# Can't run SABERTOOTH 2X32 with STM32 G431RB, communication issue

Tags: stm32, motordriver

i am having trouble with driving motors with sabertooth 2x32.

I was working with Arduino between G431rb and Sabertooth 2x32. Everything is working well but not stable. I decided to remove Arduino but couldn"t handle communication between Sabertooh 2x32 and G431rb.

I checked the signals are going to the driver from arduino on the Hercules dekstop app. I tried to send these with USART but i didnt get any response.

```
    uint8_t openRightSS[5] = {0x31, 0x32, 0x30, 0x0D, 0x0A};
    // i got these hex numbers from hercules, when they sent to motor driver, motor driver works
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, openRightSS,5,100);
```

I have some sources from Dimension Engineering(for Sabertooth 2x32 packet serial communication) website. There are some informations about CRC and Checksum but i couldnt implement them also.

Last thing that i found was sending data with different way(?).

```
void driveForwardMotor1(uint8_t address, uint8_t speed)
{
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, address, strlen(address), 1000);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, 0, 1, 1000);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, speed, strlen(speed), 1000);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, ((address + 0 + speed) & (0b01111111)), strlen((address + 0 + speed) & (0b01111111)), 1000);

}
void driveBackwardMotor1(uint8_t address, uint8_t speed)
{
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, address, strlen(address), 1000);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, 1, 1, 1000);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, speed, strlen(speed), 1000);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, ((address + 1 + speed) & (0b01111111)), strlen((address + 1 + speed) & (0b01111111)), 1000);
}
void driveForwardMotor2(uint8_t address, uint8_t speed)
{
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, address, strlen(address), 1000);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, 4, 1, 1000);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, speed, strlen(speed), 1000);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, ((address + 4 + speed) & (0b01111111)), strlen((address + 4 + speed) & (0b01111111)), 1000);

}
void driveBackwardMotor2(uint8_t address, uint8_t speed)
{
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, address, strlen(address), 1000);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, 5, 1, 1000);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, speed, strlen(speed), 1000);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, ((address + 5 + speed) & (0b01111111)), strlen((address + 5 + speed) & (0b01111111)), 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue. Data i received from hercules were not working(idk why). I tried to see what arduino sent to sabertooth board through another arduino. They were different hex data arrays, i tried them with this code and it worked
`uint8_t forward[4] = {0x80, 0x00, 0x78, 0x78}; while(counter<3 { HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, forward, strlen(forward), 100); counter++; }`